# How can I customize Vant.js?

Tags: vue.js

I made it using vant.js.
I wnat to change button background. But it's not changed.
I dont' want to use `!important`.
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, please do not post code images and try to be a bit more explicit as of your issue (by showing relevant code only).

Answer (score 0):

In the [Vant 3 documentation](https://youzan.github.io/vant/#/en-US/button) you use the `color` attribute, for example...

```html
<van-button color="#7232dd">Pure</van-button>
<van-button color="#7232dd" plain>Pure</van-button>
<van-button color="linear-gradient(to right, #ff6034, #ee0a24)">
  Gradient
</van-button>
```